# Converting arbritrary size strings into arbritrary precision integers (bigints)

Tags: c, algorithm, math, types, bignum

I'm trying to implement the Solovoy-Strassen primality test for arbritrary large integers. I will also be writing a bignum (cannot use 3rd party implementation as this is an academic project). I have decided on the following structure for the bignum:

```
struct {
  uint64_t *tab;
  int size; // number of limbs
  int sign;
}
```

I will be using base-32 for my digits (hence uint64_t, for partial products, at least I assume they will be partial products). This decision was based on a [previous question asked.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2664219/what-is-a-convenient-base-for-a-bignum-library-primality-testing-algorithm)

I'm at a standstill. I cannot conceive how one can take a string represented as an arbitrary size decimal and convert it into the bignum structure above.

Could someone please enlighten me. Even a smaller example would be nice, such as converting maybe an arbitrary string into octal digits which would be stored in a uint16_t array.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried to read `mpz/set_str.c:mpz_set_str()` and `mpn/generic/set_str.c:mpn_set_str()` from `gmp` library?

Comment: Also, you misunderstood the information from the previous answer and your struct is thus funny looking. Since you are using a 64-bit type for the limbs, your base is 2**64, not 32 == 2**5.

Comment: How is it that an "academic project" cannot use GMP?  You really do not want to have to implement code as efficient and with as optimal of algorithms as they already have.  If this is a "homework project", well, sure, you're stuck, and if it's a "commercial project", maybe the license isn't okay.  But for academic use, in C, GMP will save you a ton of work.

Comment: @Rex - By academic I meant homework, but still of a project nature.
@GregS - Thanks, I just clarified with my prof, that we're allowed to use fixed-size arrays, so I think I'll use 32 or 64-bit and a fixed size to store 1000 decimal digits.
@J.F. Sebastian: Thanks, I've been looking at it. It's a little hard to comprehend because of the deep nature of gmp, but it certainly has given a good starting point.

Answer (score 3):

You need to do the arithmetic, calling your routines. For example, if the string is "2013" (representing 2013 in decimal), do: `a=0; a=10*a+2; a=10*a+0; a=10*a+1; a=10*a+3`.

Comment: One can probably take 9 digits at a time, use the system-provided `toInt()` conversion, and then convert that into to `BigInt` before multiplying - should add some efficiency.

Comment: By last 9 digits, you mean the number of decimal digits that can be stored in a single digit of the base. That seems reasonable. But there will be a digit that will be in the intersection of two consecutive digits. I just don't know how to handle that case (yet).

Comment: OpenSSL bn does that. See BN_dec2bn for instance in http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/OpenSSL098/OpenSSL098-27/src/crypto/bn/bn_print.c

Comment: @nn - you need not worry about intersection of consecutive digits. doing 9 digits at a time is not really different from doing 1 digit at a time - just a tad faster. The example 2013 is not that great because it does not force you to think that a is a `BigInt` and not an `int'. So, Step 1) input = '12345123456789123456789', BigInt  result = new BigInt(0), BigInt multiplier = BigInt(1) 2) input = '12345123456789', result += multiplier * int('123456789'), multiplier *= 1000000000 3) input = '12345', result += multiplier * int('123456789'), multiplier *= 1000000000, 4) //finally computes the res.